# JTable - color selection of a line

Tags: jtable

I have a JTable where I have in the first column of a JPanel. The problem is that when I select a line, all cells of the line changing the background color except the cell that contains the JPanel.

So I want the cell that contains the JPanel will also change the background color.

Comment: Please provide the information in Universal language. Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! For certain reasons, this site runs in English (maybe you came here through an automatic translator?). It's ok if your English isn't perfect, but you probably won't get answers in other languages.

Comment: @Mohamed Saligh: Do you mean Latin or Esperanto? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a custom cell renderer. See [the tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer).

Comment: thanks, effectively i implements cellRenderer, but i can't have solution to this case.